# What effect does sludge have?

Tags: sanctum-2

In the "slums" (the level with sludge covering the ground and with zombie-like humanoids), what effect does the sludge have? I know that it damages you when you touch it, but I have no idea what effect it has on the "lumes" (the name for the enemies in sanctum 2). It appears to give them damage buffs, and maybe defense buffs, and also appears to have an additional effects on the zombie-explorers. What is the exact nature if these buffs, if they even exist?

Comment: Tags don't get cleaned up on this site, so don't worry about usage count.

Comment: I tried to find some more info on this and submitted a retag to Sanctum 1. The wiki page clearly lists "Slums" as a Sanctum (1) map
http://sanctum.wikia.com/wiki/Slums.

Comment: Disregard previous comment, I searched some more. :) http://sanctum.gamepedia.com/The_Slums No info is available on the sludge though.